# Scriptaculous highlight effect on php print

Tags: php, javascript, prototypejs, scriptaculous

I want this effect when php print gets called . How can i do it?

I have tried with

`print "<span  id=\"highlight\" onLoad=\"Effect.Highlight(highlight);\"><em>Your post was successfully added.</em></span>"."<hr>";`

but this is not working. Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it does not need to be in the php itself then use (advise against using short tags to open and close):

```
?>
<span id="highlight" onLoad="Effect.Highlight(this.id);"><em>Your post was successfully added.</em></span><hr>
<?php
```

and continue your script.

alternatively,

```
<head>
...
object.onload="SomeJavaScriptCode";
...
</head>
```

--EDIT--

Javascript would look like:

```
<script type="javascript/text">
body.onload=Effect.Highlight(getElemenyById('highlight'));
</script>
```

-- EDIT --

Javascript, I believe, (thanks to comments) will look like:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
Effect.Highlight(getElemenyById('highlight'));
}, false);
```

Comment: There can only be one handler in `body.onload`, assigning another removes the former. Best practice here is to use a [`dom:loaded`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/document/observe/) event.

Answer (score 0):

```
onload=""
```

Does only work inside of a `<body>, <frame>, <frameset>, iframe, <img>, <input type="image">, <link>, <script> or <style>` Tag.

Comment: this is not true, onload runs on a number of elements. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp

Answer (score 0):

if you are using javascript why not print in your script section?

in your body you can have the notice hidden,
and after the post is added to the database you can show and highlight the alert.
are you using Ajax?

an example:

```
<span id="hightlight" style="display:none"><em>Your post was successfully added.</em></span>
<scrpt type="text/javascript">
<?php
  print "$('highlight').show(); Effect.Highlight('highlight')";
?>
</script>
```